# FFmpeg Converted files not working on firefox

Tags: html, firefox, video, ffmpeg, video.js

When i convert a file with ffmpeg and play the video in firefox i get this error :

```
"VIDEOJS:" "ERROR:" "(CODE:3 MEDIA_ERR_DECODE)" "The video playback was aborted due to a     corruption problem or because the video used features your browser did not support." Object { code: 3, message: "The video playback was aborted due to a corruption problem or because the video used features your browser did not support." }
```

In other browsers it's working perfect.
This is my ffmpeg convert command:

```
ffmpeg -i {input} -b 5500k -minrate 5500k -maxrate 5500k -bufsize 5500k -ab 384k -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict -2 -ac 2 -ar 96000 -s 1280x720 -y {output}
```

Can someone tell me why the videos won't play in firefox?

Comment: it seems the error explains though - `\video used features your browser did not support`

Comment: Look at this post - [FFMPEG converted mp4 file does not play in firefox and chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184014/ffmpeg-converted-mp4-file-does-not-play-in-firefox-and-chrome)

Comment: @Coffee Yeah But which features? Because then i can change the command.

Comment: @Coffee It is working in chrome and in opera so it's only firefox

Comment: possibly try -pix_fmt yuv420p ?